# Disable/enable one checkbox on deselecting other checkbox in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

1)

```
<h:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
        value="#{CertificateInsuranceAddRq.insuranceSvcRq.com_csc_CertificateInsuranceAddRq.com_csc_CertificateInfo.com_csc_RenewalInd}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="continuous" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{label.renewable}" style="font-weight:bold" />
</h:column>
```

2)

```
<h:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="continuous"
        disabled="#{!CertificateInsuranceAddRq.insuranceSvcRq.com_csc_CertificateInsuranceAddRq.com_csc_CertificateInfo.com_csc_RenewalInd}"
        value="#{CertificateInsuranceAddRq.insuranceSvcRq.com_csc_CertificateInsuranceAddRq.com_csc_CertificateInfo.contractTerm.continuousInd}">
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{label.contUntilCancel}" style="font-weight:bold" />
</h:column>
```

In this I have two checkbox, one is renewable(by default check) and other is continous until cancel. I want that when I deselect the renewable checkbox the other checkbox should be disabled.

Currently it not working and when I deselect the renewable checkbox the other checkbox is not getting disabled (it's getting disabled only when I click on window after deselecting) .

Please give me the way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="continuous" />
```

to

```
<p:ajax event="click" update="continuous" />
```

ie seems to accept the change only on focus out

Comment: Hi,thanks !!its working fine but when i deselect one checkbox its remain checked.